# Have text file; need to search and extract to website

Tags: button

I have programming knowledge in Java, C++, C, C# and basic HTML. I just need some general direction of where to start with this task.

Do I need a database, like how would one go about doing this?

Books, subjects, keywords to look up, any help would be appreciated.

Basically I want user to click a button on website and have text from file go onto the site.

How hard is this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest prototype of this I can think of is to use an HTML form and a PHP backend. On button click, submit the form and have the PHP process it on the backend. That can happen at `http://yoursite.com/foo.php`.

The backend then reads the content, **sanitizes it**, saves it to flat file or a database, and then sends out an "ok" type web page to the user.

Then, in another location on your site, say `http://yoursite.com/bar.php`, you simply read from that flat file or database, to display what the user put in.

Sure they could be the same page but then the code is more complex.

Simplistic, and not without security considerations, but hopefully it's enough to get you started down the right path.

I would not use C/C++ for this task, and Java or C# would be okay, but involve more effort than what I mention above.

Answer (score 0):

**C#, ASP.NET**

- create an asp.net web page
- put button on it
- put label and give it ID lblText
- On button click read file like this:

  ```
  var file = "full_path_to_a_file";  //like "C:\\textfile.txt"
  var text = File.ReadAllText(file);
  ```
- then attach text to your label

  ```
  lblText.Text = text;
  ```

or whatever you want to do